# Selenium How can I select when element increases by one?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-ide

For example I have an xpath like below.

```
(//textarea[@placeholder='text'])[1]
```

This xpath [1] is generated from 1 to 100 Sequentially.

```
(//textarea[@placeholder='text'])[1]
(//textarea[@placeholder='text'])[2]
(//textarea[@placeholder='text'])[3]
(//textarea[@placeholder='text'])[4]
(//textarea[@placeholder='text'])[5]
```

I need to enter text after selecting these.
How can I choose [1],[2],[3],[4] these at this time?

I am using java and I know I have to use the for statement, but I don't know how to do it.
Can you check by increasing only part of the xpath?

Comment: Can you explain more ? Do you want to locate the `xpath` with increment ?

Comment: So you have hundred text fields and you want to enter text in all of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making a list of textbox elements like this.

```
List<WebElement> elms = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//textarea[@placeholder='text']"));
    for (WebElement elm:elms) {
        elm.sendKeys("Text");
    }
```